# How to translateZ absolutely on camera in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using the translateZ function so that camera can move forward/backward along its lookat direction. But translateZ moves it relatively. So `camera.translateZ(10);` followed by another `camera.translateZ(10);` will move the camera by 20 units in total. Because of this, I can't use it in a tween animation where I tween the parameter inside of that function.

So I was wondering if there's a way to translate along Z in absolute coordinates, for example if I'm looking at object in origin, I'd like to set distance_from_origin while still maintaining lookat direction?

```
camera.absTranslateZ(distance_from_origin);
```

Comment: `camera.position.setZ`

Comment: @AndyRay just checked, it didn't maintain lookat direction like translateZ does.

Comment: You could do linear algebra to find the point on the line of the camera vector where Z = your distance, or you could setZ then lookAt again

Comment: I'm confused by what you're asking. Are you looking to get a "fly-by" effect, where you continue to watch a single point as the camera travels in the Z direction? Or are you saying you want to be able to use `translateZ` in "camera space"?

Comment: @TheJim01 translateZ is in object space and receives a relative parameter. so if you go translateZ(10) twice, it'll move the cam 20 units. I want it in world space and to not be relative.

Comment: @foreyez Did you try the approach in my answer below? It resets the camera position on each frame, so no matter how many times you use `translateZ(10)`, it'll always be only 10 units away from the focus point.

Answer (score 1):

I use something similar on all my camera rigs. I only need 2 variables: the focus position (vec3) and the z-distance. I then reset the position on each frame:

```
var focusPos = new THREE.Vector3();
var zDist = 10;

// Called once per frame
update() {
    // reset camera position
    camera.position.copy(focusPos);

    // Set camera rotations if needed
    // camera.rotation.set(rotX, rotY, 0);

    // Apply z-translation to dolly in/out
    camera.translateZ(zDist);
}
```

I like this approach because it lets you change and even tween the focus position, so you're not always looking at the origin. However, it depends on how you're calculating your camera rotations, you might run into gimbal lock if you need more complex rotations.

Comment: my scene is centered at the origin, I wanted to tween the zDist. but I think you're tweening the focusPos? I just wanted to be able to dolly the camera in and out while looking at the origin.

Comment: `focusPos` is at (0,0,0) so it doesn't need to change. The value you want to update is `zDist` to dolly in/out.

Comment: then instead of camera.translateZ(zDist) above I'd do TWEEN.update(); then var anim = new TWEEN.Tween({ val: 0  }).to({ val: 200 }, 2000).onUpdate(function(value) {
     camera.translateZ(value.val); 
  }).start(); doesn't seem to work.